# How to check if user has clicked on the link in google sheet using google apps script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, web-applications

I have been working on providing an google sheets interface for non technical members in my team, where they can see a sheet of info on some members, and one of those fields is a link to accessing that resource on an internal portal. The sheet looks as shown in the image attached.
[This is an example sheet of the same type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PbIQE.png)

This sheet will be accessible to these non technical team, who are going to have a look at this sheet, and if they want to work on a certain case, they will click on the link. What I want to ensure is that, when they get redirected to this url, I want to ensure that that particular row gets deleted from the sheet.

My initial problem is that I dont know what trigger should be used for making such a program. The one that seems most likely is a `doGet(event)` found [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#dogete_and_doposte)
The second one is how to do i catch an event like this and associate it to a particular cell.
A secondary solution could be that of an `onClick(event)` which would really make things simpler here, but that is not a "simple Trigger"

**Note:- The good thing is that each resource is going to be unique**

I could really use some ideas, i have drafted a little bit of a pseudo code here for the same, but it seems very hacks, and not computationally feasible:-

```
function doGet(event){
// code to delete a certain row when they visit the portal
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var s = event.source.getActiveSheet();
var r = event.source.getActiveRange();
if (s.getName = "clicker_checker" && check which url redirected){
  check which row and cell matches with the redirections url, and delete that.  
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using a spreadsheet, the most suitable trigger for you would be an `onSelectionChange` one.

This trigger will allow you to detect when a selection has been made in this spreadsheet- more particularly in the cell wanted.

Therefore, you can use a script similar to this:

```
function onSelectionChange(e) {
  var range = e.range;
  var sheet = range.getSheet();
  var col = range.getColumn(); //if needed
  var row = range.getRow(); //if needed
  if (sheet.getName() = "clickeer_checker" && other_condition) {
     // instructions here
  }
}
```

#### Reference

- [Apps Script Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but i think that only solves half of my problem, because, a selection will make them see the resource, but i want to ensure that they are landed on the url, with a hard redirect. For this I have drafted a solution, using an onedit and a checkbox. So when the box is checked, they will be redirected to the website! Will post my code here when it works! :-)

Comment: There is no method to check if the user has visited the actual that is supported in Apps Script. I think that for that you will have to handle this on the site part.